# SQLite - value at range

Tags: sqlite

I am updating my table with the following statement:

```
UPDATE table SET percentage = percentage + ? WHERE id = ?
```

And the value that is being passed to the database may be positive and negative as well.

Is there a way to make sure that the percentage value is going to lie in the range of 0..100? Desirable to accomplish it, using only SQLite.

If it is less than 0 I want to make it 0; If it is more than 100 I want to make it 100.

I can have it done through my C code, but it would be better to have it done through SQLite.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE table SET percentage 
= case when percentage < 0 then 0 
  when percentage > 100 then 100 
  else percentage end
WHERE id = ?;
```

If you leave off the `where` clause, you'll set percentages for the entire table, which is presumably what you want.

However, it may be that percentages greater than 100 or less than zero are legitimate; I don't know your problem domain.

Comment: Thank you, I did the following: "UPDATE table SET percentage = case WHEN (percentage + ?) < 0 then 0 WHEN (percentage + ?) > 100 then 100 ELSE (percentage + ?) END WHERE word_id = ?";
Do I have to bind the same value for all 3 symbols "?" ? Or there is a way to do it once?

Comment: You don't need to bind anything except the id. Use the statement I gave you /as-is/. Or you can omit the where clause, and use it.